# Android - AsyncTask not executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know there are already a lot of questions with this title but I still haven't found a solution to work for my case.

I have the following code that gets the users data from an online database. The problem is, as stated in the title, that the `AsyncTask` doesn't start.

Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getData(); // retrieves "friends" data from database
    FloatingActionButton btn3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_add_new_friend);
    btn3.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.Blonde));
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(profile.this);
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_new_friend, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(profile.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

            final EditText editText1 = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_addnewfriend);

            // setup a dialog window
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                        InputStream is = null;

                        // add values to the database
                        String friend = "" + editText1.getText();

                        // Verify the user in the USERS database - get users data from the dabase
                        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
                        g.execute();                                
                        if (friends.contains(friend)) // if you are already friends with that user
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already friends with that user!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else {
                            if (!users.contains(friend)) // the user doesn't exist in our database
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That user doesn't exist! You either haven't introduced the right email or he's not a registered user within Poinder.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else // the user exists so we add him to the friends list
                        {
                            //do something
                        }
}

// Getting the users
protected void showList2(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        people = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<people.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = people.getJSONObject(i);
            String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            Double location_latitude = c.getDouble(TAG_LATITUDE);
            Double location_longitude = c.getDouble(TAG_LONGITUDE);

            users.add(email);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// Getting the users
private class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxx/friends_out.php");

        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        myJSON=result;
        showList2();
    }
}
```

Any idea what other method I should use instead? Or preferably how I should modify this one to work and any ideas why my `AsyncTask` never starts?

EDIT: I applied all the suggestions mentioned below and unfortunately none of them work so far (my `AsyncTask` still doesn't start).

And another question: using more than one `AsyncTask` in the same activity has anything to do with my problem?

Comment: You have created showList2() method and from postexecute you are calling showList() method.... Strange

Comment: How do you know the AsyncTask is not being executed? Maybe an exception is thrown during the execution of the task which you ignore silently, so you don't see anything happen.

Comment: Why do you declare a class within a method? It is a really bad practice. At most you can declare that class private in the scope of your Activity, not method

Comment: From your code, I don't see where you show the `alertDialogBuilder` dialog, do you already show it? Beside of that, do you add any log in `doinBackground` to make sure your task didn't run?

Comment: As [Minhtdh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1460035/minhtdh) highlighted that you are not showing the alert dialog. As per your code the control will reach the asynctask(g.execute();) only when user press the "OK" button of the alert dialog. But here alert box is not displayed. Hence, no "OK" button is shown/pressed and no AsyncTask is executed.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, I suggest using the recommended 4-space indentation (and code comments) to help other developers better understand your problem.

Comment: Use some logs in your code to see what is working and where does it stop. Also, when you catch the exception use `Log.e("Error doInBackground", e.toString())` to see if there's the problem.

Comment: Is there another AsyncTask running that never stops? In the newest version of Android (LOLLIPOP and higher) only one AsyncTask at a time is allowed to be running. If another is started it will wait with it's execution until the former AsyncTask is finished.

Answer (score 35):

Since (I assume) none of the other suggested solutions work, I suspect that your problem lies in the way `AsyncTask`s are executed. If multiple AsyncTasks are executing in the same Activity, like in your app, then those AsyncTasks will not execute in parallel. They will execute one after the other.

I suspect that your other AsyncTask(s) are long running, so that your `GetDataJSON` AsyncTask is waiting for the other tasks to complete.

The solution is to enable parallel execution of AsyncTask. Use the following code to execute AsyncTasks in parallel.

```
GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
g.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

From AsyncTask docs:

> Order of execution
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey this works for me with Activity. But what about fragment? I mean if two different AsyncTasks are inside two fragments, then would it be executed parallelly using THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR?

Comment: @Srushti Both AsyncTasks are actually going to be loaded on the Activity's UI thread. It will be the same as starting the two AyncTasks in your Activity itself.

Answer (score 11):

just change your asyntask parameters

```
 class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

to,

```
 class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

Answer (score 10):

From your question I concluded that you are trying to get the friends list from the server and based on result you will show the Toast message.

As per your code, you are not creating and showing the AlertDialog from alertDialogBuilder. Try to show the AlertBox.

As AsyncTask runs in a separate thread. Hence, the

```
if (friends.contains(friend))
```

will immediately execute after

```
 g.execute();
```

So, even the user is in friend list, it will show the Toast of the else part.

Also, you didn't put the logs in the Asynctask methods, this might be giving you the impression that AsyncTask is not running.

I will suggest you to move your `if` condition code from `AlertDialog` to `onPostExecute()` method of the `GetDataJSON` and put it after `showList2();`.
Also, put some logs in the AsyncTask methods.

Hope this will help. Please find the bellow code for your reference:

```
public class AIssue extends Activity {
String result = " DATA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                            .permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            AIssue.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
                                    g.execute();

                                }
                            });
                    alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
                }
            });
}

// Getting the users
private class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.e("IN", "ONPRE EXECUTE");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = "SOME DATA";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.e("IN", "DO IN BACKGROUND");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = "ERROR";
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("IN", "ON POST EXECUTE");
        Log.e("IN", "" + result);
        /*****
         * Your Condition to Check The Friend should be here after
         * showList2();
         * ***/
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("SOME DATA"))// replace it with your
                                                    // condition to check
                                                    // friends
        {
            Log.e("IN", "IF");
        } else {
            Log.e("IN", "ELSE");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside  getData2()  method try this:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // your code
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
           // your code
        }
    }.execute();
```

or if it does not work, put AsyncTask class outside method and then directly make call to execute AsyncTask class instead of getData2(), like this

```
new GetDataJSON().execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

add this override method in Aysc Task.

```
 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
```

I dont know what u r trying to do here but this code will execute before ur async task finish.

```
if (friends.contains(friend)) // if you are already friends with that user
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already friends with that user!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    else {
                                        if (!users.contains(friend)) // the user doesn't exist in our database
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That user doesn't exist! You either haven't introduced the right email or he's not a registered user within Poinder.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        else // the user exists so we add him to the friends list
                                        {
                                            //do something
                                        }
```

If u want this code execute after ur asyc task finish then add this code inside ur showList2() method.

By the way, why u r creating async task inside inner method. Its bad idea.
Create separate aynch task. so that u can use from another activity.

Answer (score 4):

Add a constructor on the AsyncTask

```
public GetDataJSON (){
}
```

Add its onPreExecute to be more sure

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Toast.makeText(this /*or getActivity()*/,"IT'S WORKING!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think forcing Strict Mode is helping in this situation. You should use AsyncTask instead of Strict Mode when coding network operations (like the ones you're doing inside doInBackground method) so your UI doesn't get blocked.

Strict Mode will force operations to run on the application's main thread, while AsyncTask runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your asynctask parameters

Google's Android Documentation Says that :

An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

AsyncTask's generic types :

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

Google's Android Documentation Says that :

AsyncTask's generic types :

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
   background computation.
3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

So as your not sending any params to the AsyncTask  make your async task like below

```
 // Getting the users
    public void getData2(){
   new GetDataJSON().execute();  
    }


class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                /// your logic here
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                // your logic here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this problem, quite usual, that I introduced to my current development is AsyncService, I won't use all the features of this library (the ache system) but is powerfull and it also helps you to clean code in your activities.

1. You declare your service, wich is going to retrieve data, with the @AsyncService annotation
2. You inject the service in your activity
3. Call your service wherever you need
4. Declare a method inside your activity with the annotation @OnMessage where you are going to deal with the service response...

[AsyncService GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-asyncservice/wiki/Basics)

I don't know if exists another solution that helps developers to separate concerns and clean the code (in Android I mean) like this, this is the bests I tried and maybe you should give it a try too. For sure it will help you with your current problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Neat, I like it!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I wrote this more than two years ago.